# This workflow cannot run because arguments provided by parent workflow does not match with the specified parameters in linked child workflow

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I am trying to call Dynamics CRM workflow from my C# code. My workflow expects parameters from my C# code. I am using flowing code:

```
var workflowInfo = result.Entities.FirstOrDefault();
if (workflowInfo != null)
{
InputArgumentCollection inputParameters = new InputArgumentCollection();

EntityReference reference = new EntityReference();
reference.Id = paymentRunID;
reference.Name = "paymentrunid";
reference.LogicalName = "paymentrun";                    
inputParameters.Add("InputPaymentRunID", reference);

inputParameters.Add("InputPaymentDueDate", paymentRunPayDate);

OptionSetValue opt = new OptionSetValue();
opt.Value = region;
inputParameters.Add("InputRegion", opt);

var request = new ExecuteWorkflowRequest();
request.WorkflowId = workflowInfo.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("workflowid"); //ID of the workflow to execute
request.EntityId = paymentRunID; //ID of the record on which the workflow executes                    
request.InputArguments = inputParameters;

ServerConnection.CrmService.Execute(request);
return true;
}
```

Code at my CRM workflow side is:

```
[RequiredArgument]
[Input("EntityReference input")]
[ReferenceTarget("paymentrun")]
public InArgument<EntityReference> InputPaymentRunID { get; set; }

[Input("DateTime input")]
public InArgument<DateTime> InputPaymentDueDate { get; set; }

[Input("OptionSetValue input")]
[Default("1")]
[AttributeTarget("paymentrun", "lregion")]
public InArgument<OptionSetValue> InputRegion { get; set; }
```

When I run my C# code, it's executed successfully and returns true but at my Dynamics CRM workflow side I am getting following error:

```
This workflow cannot run because arguments provided by parent workflow does not match with the specified parameters in linked child workflow. Check the child workflow reference in parent workflow and try running this workflow again.

Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.Crm.CrmException: This workflow cannot run because arguments provided by parent workflow does not match with the specified parameters in linked child workflow. Check the child workflow reference in parent workflow and try running this workflow again.
at Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.Services.InputArgumentValidator.VerifyAndFilterInputParametersSupplied(Dictionary`2 inputArguments, Dictionary`2 childParameters)
at Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.ActivityHostBase.FetchInputArguments(ICommonWorkflowContext context)
at Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.ActivityHost.StartWorkflowExecution(Activity workflow, ICommonWorkflowContext context)
at Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.ActivityHostBase.StartWorkflow(ICommonWorkflowContext context, Activity preLoadedActivity)
```

What is wrong in C# code or workflow code.

Comment: The `dynamics` part of code you've provided it is **not** a `Workflow` it is a `custom activity`. To make it run it you should use it as part of `workflow`, which will supply the parameters inside your custom step (based on custom activity). Please check your `Workflow` content (not an `Activity`) what is there and if it still not gives you an answer, share the content in the question

Comment: Have to see your UI workflow screenshot where you are calling this custom WF activity. Seems some child WF being called, right? Is this UI workflow running successfully when trigger from CRM UI ? (May be on demand)

Answer (score 0):

*I'm going to assume you are not using a [XAML workflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309458.aspx) here.*

I think you have confused a workflow with a custom workflow activity (CWA), and even then I think your design is probably wrong.

A workflow is a process configured via the CRM user interface using the workflow designer. A workflow contains a number of steps. Workflows can be triggered by system events, and the `ExecuteWorkflowRequest` call.

A CWA is a piece of code you can package and place inside a process as a step. The CWA can only be triggered via a process. You cannot use the `ExecuteWorkflowRequest` call to direct access a CWA. You need to design a process and then add your CWA into it as a step, passing the inputs via the workflow designer.

Your implementation suggests you want to create a endpoint you can pass arguments to and then run some custom code. In this case a workflow won't work in any case - it cannot recieve inputs (which I suspect is the cause of your error). You should consider an action (another [type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309471.aspx) of process) which allows input arguments to be defined. The action is also implemented using the workflow designer, so you can call your CWA and then pass through the arguments from the action.